Projective lines and minors of matrices
Consider the $3\times (n+1)$ matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 & ... & x_n\\
a_0 & a_1 & ... & a_n\\
b_0 & b_1 & ... & b_n
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
with variables $x_i$ and fixed constants $a_i,b_i$, such that the two lower rows are linear independent. When we compute the determinant of $3\times 3$ submatrices, we get linear equations. For example when considering the first submatrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 & x_2\\
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 \\
b_0 & b_1 & b_2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
by using Laplace's Theorem, we get the determinant
$$ x_0(a_1b_2-b_1a_2) - x_1(a_0b_2-b_0a_2) + x_2(a_0b_1-b_0a_1).$$
As every possible $3\times 3$ submatrix generates such an linear equation (set this equal to $0$), we end up with in total $\binom{n+1}{3}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}$ many such linear equations.
However, it is claimed now that there are only $n-1$ many linear independent equations, and any other equation can be expressed as linear combination of the first $n-1$ ones. Why does this happen?
For example, consider
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
then by regarding the first and last submatrix, we get the expressions
\begin{align*}
I:-3x_0+3x_1-x_2\\
II:3x_1+2x_2-3x_3
\end{align*}
When I now consider the submatrices I obtain when neglecting the second and third column, this gives the equations
\begin{align*}
3x_0+3x_2-3x_3=II-I\\
-2x_0+3x_1-x_3 = \frac{1}{3}II+\frac{2}{3}I.
\end{align*}
Approach: If any point $(x_0,..,x_n)$ fulfills such an $=0$ linear equations, than this means that the the corresponding $3\times 3$ matrix has not full rank, that is in our case rank $2$. If any point fulfills all our linear equations, this means that the $3\times (n+1)$ matrix does have rank two too, as no $3$ linear independet coloumns exist in this case. I think that this is related to the fact that $n+1-2=n-1$ using the rank-nullity theorem and relate the problem to the fact that there are  $n-1$ linear independet kernel elements. However, I am unable to put this together. In particular, I struggle with the fact that this system of equations is not obtained like usually in linear algebra 1, but by choosing certain minors of a matrix where the variables itself form a row. I do not know how to translate the meaning of rank and kernel in the context of a "normal" system of linear equations given by matrices to this setup.
Context: I encounterted this question in the context of the line that conntects two points $P=[a_0:...:a_n]$, $Q=[b_0:...:b_n]$ in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$. The points on the line are precisely the values for $x$ that fulfill all linear equations. However, as lines are linear varieties of dimension $1$, it is known that precisely $n-1$ independet linear equations are required to do this. Consequently, if I'd use even more of these linear equations which I am able to generate and if they were not linear dependent from the previous $n-1$ ones, then this would further lower the dimension of the variety, which should not happen in reality.
It is possible answer my question precisely this way around, "there are only $n-1$ linear independet equations because a line has dimension $1$", but this is quite unsatisfying as I want to understand the purely algebraic reason for that only considering the matrix above.
I would really appreciate any help on this.

Consider the matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & ... & a_n\\
b_0 & b_1 & ... & b_n
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Since the rank of this matrix is $2$, the kernel is spanned precisely by $n-1$ independent vectors $(A_0,\ldots,A_n)^{T}$. Each of this vector can be used to give one independent equation $A_0x_0+\cdots+A_nx_n=0$ satisfied by the points $[a_0:a_1:\cdots:a_n]$ and $[b_0:b_1:\cdots:b_n]$.
In your particular example, if $(A,B,C,D)^T$ is in the kernel of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
then you can show that $A=3C+2D$ and $B=-3C-3D$, so the kernel is spanned, say for example, by $(-3,3,-1,0)^T$ and $(0,3,2,-3)^T$, which correspond exactly to the coefficients of linear forms you wrote.

Thank you very much. This essentially answers my question.
However, can you still provide an answer concerning my approach using the minors?

Adjoining the variables $x_i$ makes me uncomfortable, since the resulting matrix is over a polynomial ring and not over a field, but I guess we are just thinking of them as unknown elements from $k$. Anyways, the point is that your matrix has rank $2$ iff all $3\times 3$ minors vanish. So you get a bunch of equations $\sum_j A_{ij}x_j=0$. In particular, we know that the matrix has rank two when $x_j=a_j$ for all $j$ or $x_j=b_j$ for all $j$. So $\sum_j A_{ij}a_j=\sum_j A_{ij}b_j=0$, and hence we see that $(A_{i,0},\ldots,A_{i,n})^{T}$ is in the kernel of my matrix $M$....

But $\dim_k \ker M=n-1$. (I may have gotten some indices wrong.)
